# Datalist control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

in my web application, I am using  datalist, in that i am displaying images and below that  i am displaying name of that image. I am displaying images in horizontal and display 5 images for a row. My problem is due to the long length of the image name the space between cells are huge. Can we display the name in second line.

Please help if u do not understand my problem tell me I will explain once again.

this is source code

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" RepeatColumns="9" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
     runat="server" Width="719px" >
   <ItemTemplate>
     <center>
       <img src='AlumniGallery/compressed/<%# Eval("Photoname")%>' id="img1" 
           width="75px" height="85px"/><br />           
       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" ForeColor="black" CssClass="xyz" 
           Width="165px" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Photoname")%>'  
           CommandName='<%# Eval("slno")%>' runat="server" 
           OnCommand="LinkButton2_Command"><%# Eval("name")%></asp:LinkButton>
     </center> </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Totally unclear, bad English, not the first time. -1

Comment: Can you post the code for displaying images inside the datalist?

Comment: bad english is not a reason for down vote. If you can then try to improve the grammar and spelling in the question.

Comment: just i send my source code please verify

Comment: i just spelled correctly my question please veryfi

Comment: @Surya it is Verify :) please use Firefox or Chrome it tell you about such simple spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this:

```
  <ItemStyle Width="100px" Wrap="true" /> //this will limit width of the 
                                          //item and wrap long text
  <ItemTemplate>
```